# Van Kampen's $\Omega$-Expansion contains incorrect reasoning

Tags: statistical-mechanics

#### Problem

Essentially the problem with Van Kampen's logic is that he has a function where the coefficient of $x$ is a large number ($\Omega^{1/2}$). He then factors out a bigger number ($\Omega$) and absorbs it into the function so that the coefficient of $x$ is now a small number:

$$f(\Omega \phi+ \Omega^{1/2} x) = f(\Omega (\phi +\Omega^{-1/2} x)) = f_\Omega(\phi + \Omega^{-1/2} x) $$

He then claims to be able to Taylor expand the function in the small quantity $\Omega^{-1/2}x$, such that each of the successive terms of the expansion are smaller by an order $\Omega^{-1/2}$. **This is clearly incorrect.**

If I taylor expand the function:

$$ f_\Omega (\phi + \Omega^{-1/2} x ) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}  f^n_\Omega (\phi)\Omega^{-n/2} x^n $$

Since $\frac{d^n}{dn^n} f_\Omega (n) = \frac{d^n}{dn^n} f (\Omega n) = \Omega^n \frac{d^n}{dn^n}f_\Omega $

$$ f_\Omega (\phi + \Omega^{-1/2} x ) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}  f^n (\phi)\Omega^{n/2} x^n $$

we see the terms are actually increasing in $\Omega$:

Is there anyone here who is an expert on this expansion who can explain it to me better?

EDIT: a simple counterexample is

$$ \sin m = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} x^n $$

what if $\phi = 0$, then this becomes:

$$ \sin(\Omega (\Omega^{-1/2}x))= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \Omega^{2n+1} (\Omega^{-1/2}x)^{2n+1} $$

each term in this series is actually *increasing* in powers of $\Omega^{1/2}$, not decreasing.

Comment: The logic is perfectly correct, you simply have to remember what you are keeping constant, and what scales with $\Omega$.

Comment: To see that there is no problem, note that you can start with literally any series expansion you think is good, introduce $\Omega$ artificially, and then run your derivation to "prove" that the expansion doesn't work.

Comment: The point that Van Kampen asserts s that each coefficient of $x$ in the expansion is smaller by an factor of $\Omega^{-1/2}$ relative to the previous one, but this is incorrect because there is a hidden $\Omega$ in the $f^n$'s

Comment: Let us suppose there are two functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$, where $g(x) = h(\Omega x)$. Which one of the functions has a "hidden $\Omega$" in the derivatives? Is it obviously $g$? What about the fact that $h(x) = g(\Omega^{-1} x)$?

Comment: Obviously, there isn't enough information to decide; all we know is that their derivatives are related with _relative_ powers of $\Omega$. van Kampen's reasoning works precisely if the function $f_\Omega$ is the one with normal-sized derivatives and $f$ is the one with "hidden $\Omega$" in the derivatives, which should ultimately be justified physically if you read on.

Comment: Ok, if true. I'm not sure it's justified physically though...